# Rendering problems while creating a menu in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, menu, android-studio

I wanted to create a simple menu for an app. Here is the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/magnify"
          android:title="New Game"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/magnify"
          android:title="Help" />
</menu>
```

But when I click on the design Tab, it gives an error saying that 
"Rendering Problems
The following classes cannot be found
-item(Fix build path, Edit in XML)
-menu(Fix build path, Edit in XML)"

What should I do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have some attributes in your menu that aren't valid - they're layout attributes, not menu attributes.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/magnify"
          android:title="New Game"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/magnify"
          android:title="Help"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" 
    />
</menu>
```

Comment: It gives an error saying that "layout_height" and "layout_width" should be defined